# Some newbie questions about branding

Tags: branding, identity

I'm new to this and im tasked to do a logo and branding guidelines for a small retail brand. I have a few questions for the experts here:

1. When presenting to clients (and eventually showing to my porfolio), can I just get photos online of what kind of photos I want to achieve? Since they still dont have any photos of their products too.
2. For typeface and colours, is the brand only limited to using the typeface and colours  i specified on the guideline?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you can use stock photos in a presentation as references as long as you mention the source. When the work is approved, the client needs to produce their own photos or buy the original stock images for commercial work. Check the copyright for any kind of photo material you include in your drafts and make sure you can actually use that.
2. Generally yes, the guideline is supposed to set the rules for typography for print and digital. But then, there's no branding police to check if somebody's doing what the guidebook says. A client takes the guideline and decides how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks! For presenting my work in my portfolio, do I only have to use photos that were actually used by the brand? Cause Im sure they wont get to achieve the photos I want. Can I just get something online and then just put the source of the photo?

Comment: I don't know that. Are you doing this work for the client or for your portfolio? :) Want future clients to see fictional work that doesn't exist in real life?

Comment: For a client. Then after finishing this ill put it in my portfolio. So when putting branding work, the photos used should be the actual photos that were taken from the brand? Cause im thinking the photos will just be a guide or reference